# PHP code error Help me

Tags: php, error-handling

```
 if(isset($_GET['u']) && !empty($_GET['u'])){

    $url = base64_decode($_GET['u']);

    $browser = Browser::detect(); 

    if($browser == 'webkit'){

        echo '
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Redirecting...</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15.5; URL='.$url.'">

        </head>
        </html>';

        exit(0);
```

**Hello

Error writing php code between html tag**

Comment: Close bracket } for if

Comment: Söylediğiniz şeyi anlayamadım hocam. Benim sorunum html tagları içerisine php kodu yazdığımda hata veriyor.

Comment: Yazdığınız kodda hata alınan yer if parantezinin kapanmaması, bunun haricinde bir hata alıyorsanız daha detaylı şekilde sormalısınız, aldığınız hata nedir, bu hatayı gidermek içinn denemeler yaptınız mı bunlar nedir?

Comment: Ben size dosyanın tamamını nasıl gönderebilirim bilmiyorum.

Comment: <html>
    <head>
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15.5; URL='.$url.'">

    </head>
    </html>

Comment: Bu kısımların arasına php kodu ile bir şey yazdığımda

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'banner_system' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in 


Böyle bir hata veriyor

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['u']) && !empty($_GET['u'])){

    $url = base64_decode($_GET['u']);

    $browser = Browser::detect(); 

    if($browser == 'webkit'){
        echo '<html><head><title>Redirecting...</title><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15.5; URL="'.$url.'"></head></html>';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Size mail attım hocam :)